# How to create beans from xml integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have code that should be rewritten to beans in java because I need to create multiple integration flows instead of one. For every customer.

I want to create JdbcPollingChannelAdapter bean for every customer using postProcessBeanFactory but I have no idea how to add channel for it.

```
<beans profile="retryProcessing">
        <bean id="jdbc-poll-for-email" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcPollingChannelAdapter">
            <constructor-arg value="dataSource"/>
            <constructor-arg value="SELECT RowID..."/>
            <property name="updateSql" value="UPDATE ${customer.catalog}...."/>
        </bean>
    </beans>

<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
            query="SELECT RowID, DocumentID..."
            channel="email.Channel" data-source="dataSource"
            update="UPDATE ${customer.catalog} SET Status=....">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="${emailAdvice.retry.period:60}" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:channel id="email.Channel"/>
    <int:chain input-channel="email.Channel" output-channel="email.headerEnricherChannel">
        <int:splitter id="splitter"/>
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="inboxType" expression="payload.get('InboxType')"/>
            <int:header name="rowId" expression="payload.get('RowID')"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int:transformer>
            <bean class="RowTransformer">
                <constructor-arg ref="transformRow"/>
            </bean>
        </int:transformer>
    </int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This section of the manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#programming-tips) shows how to find the classes involved for the channel adapter.

Specifically, you need a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` and a `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` for each one.

Also see [the java DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#java-dsl) and, specifically [Dynamic and Runtime Integration flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#java-dsl-runtime-flows) for the preferred mechanism for assembling flows programmatically.

Comment: Thank you Gary. That exactly what I need.